# Trouble with custom OnClickListener vs. in inLine OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app where I have an OnClickListener for a specific button. When i hit the button a certain method should be executed. 
When i program the onclicklistener within the onCreate block everything works fine. When I define the action outside of the oncreate method with a custom OnClickListener my app crashs if i hit the Button!

Heres the code for **inLine Version:**

```
public class OrcStopWatchActivity extends Activity {
    public String[] names;
    public String[][] gphArray;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_orc_stop_watch);
        //set up the tabhost
        TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById (R.id.tabhost);
        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("Start");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("Race");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Results");
        th.addTab(specs);


        stopBoat5Button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStopBoat5);
        textResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult);

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        String[][] gesamtArray = SvenMethods.makeArray(werteRow.txt);

        //erstelle Vektor names
        names = SvenMethods.extractColumn(gesamtArray,0);
        //  displayStringArray(names);

        //erstelle Array mit den gph Werten als double Werte ohne Namen
        gphArray = SvenMethods.deleteColumn(gesamtArray, 0);
        //  display2dStringArray(gphArray);

        //on click action of the stop buttons 
        stopBoat5Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){

                stopBoat5Button.setEnabled(false);
                    String resultString=SvenMethods.calcCorrectedTimesTest(names, gphArray);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    textResult.setText(resultString);

            }
        }
                );

    }
}
```

This one works fine, only if i change it by using a custom listener it crashs. The code changed code with custom listener is this:

```
  .....

stopBoat5Button.setOnClickListener(mStopListener5);
}

    OnClickListener mStopListener5 = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View arg0) {

            String resultString=SvenMethods.calcCorrectedTimesTest(names, gphArray);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            textResult.setText(resultString);

    }
};
```

I hope the description of the problem is somewhat understandable...i have the feeling that is has something to do with passing of the two variables names and gphArray...but I dont understand why there is a difference between the two methods of using the onClickListener.

**Logcat:**

```
01-28 11:22:38.229: D/TextLayoutCache(7668): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
01-28 11:22:38.279: D/libEGL(7668): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-28 11:22:38.289: D/libEGL(7668): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
01-28 11:22:38.309: D/libEGL(7668): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
01-28 11:22:38.309: D/libEGL(7668): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
01-28 11:22:38.399: D/OpenGLRenderer(7668): Enabling debug mode 0
01-28 11:22:38.469: D/dalvikvm(7668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 198K, 4% free 6648K/6919K, paused 4ms+4ms
01-28 11:22:46.770: D/AndroidRuntime(7668): Shutting down VM
01-28 11:22:46.770: W/dalvikvm(7668): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at methods.SvenMethods.extractColumn(SvenMethods.java:442)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at methods.SvenMethods.lowestValue(SvenMethods.java:355)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at methods.SvenMethods.calcCorrectedTimesTest(SvenMethods.java:32)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at com.orcCalculation.OrcStopWatchActivity$7.onClick(OrcStopWatchActivity.java:328)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-28 11:22:46.779: E/AndroidRuntime(7668):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!
Cheers,
Sven

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: show us your logcat output where you get crash error

Comment: The variables, names and gphArray seem to be defined in your onCreate method. Not sure how it compiles when you define your listener outside of the onCreate.  Do you have other definitons of names and gphArray?

Comment: @nr4bt: i added my logcat output (to me it always seems very hard to make anything out of that:( )

Comment: it seems the problem is solved...so i guess it was just a problem of where i had to declare my variables. before i had accidentaly  declared them twice, once inside on create and once outside. removing the declaration inside removed the problem!!! Thanks to everyone for your quick replies!

Answer (score 0):

There are several options here, but this is likely the simplest and should work:

```
View.OnClickListener mStopListener5 = new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(final View arg0) {

        String resultString=SvenMethods.calcCorrectedTimesTest(names, gphArray);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        textResult.setText(resultString);

     }

}
```